# IIS - block requests by URL pattern

Tags: iis

I have a web app hosted on IIS 7.

I need to block requests that do not match the following pattern:

`/static/index.html[\?a-zA-Z0-9_]*`

So that the following request will be blocked:

http://www.example.com/static/index.html?javascript:alert(0)

I've tried to add denyUrlSequences config in my web.config but it seems like regex patterns are not supported there.

Are there any other options?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You'll have to install the IIS URL Rewriting module. Details on how to do this can be found here:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-request-filtering-and-url-rewriting